# Can I block incoming emails to my Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I need to block someone's e-mail messages to me. I have a Gmail account. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to block a specific person from contacting you? If so, you could create filter that automatically deletes incoming email from a specific address. Please rephrase your question, and explain your problem a bit more, then you could get some good answers.

Answer (score 3):

To block someone's e-mails, create a filter. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en

Comment: Not really a block, but you can send them directly to Trash.